# How to make Docker MySQL use unicode (utf-8) with initialization scripts?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I want to insert some initial data into my db, some of which uses characters not available with `latin1`, so I switch to unicode (utf-8) with the following command:

`command: --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

This works fine for when I add rows after my container has been started, however it doesn't affect the rows from my init script. Is there a way to fix this?

For reference in my `docker-compose.yml` file I have the following setup:

```
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: [REDACTED]
      MYSQL_DATABASE: [REDACTED]
      MYSQL_USER: [REDACTED]
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: [REDACTED]
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql-init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
    command: --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
```

An example insert statement from my init script:

```
INSERT INTO vodovod_ulice (naziv)
VALUES ('Ulica Vuka Karadžića'); -- can't render `ž` or `ć`
```

Comment: the system settings just affect the defaults for new databases, and the database settings just affect the defaults for new tables, and the table settings are just the defaults for columns.  you'll need to do a bunch of alter table statements to actually change anything

Comment: do `show create table vodovod_ulice` to see the current column/table settings

Comment: Here is the result of running that command: https://pastebin.com/tsZ2BwBy. As you can see it's set to utf-8, but alas it didn't work for the init script. But adding new rows they will be correctly encoded.

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72717814/20860

Comment: avoid utfmb3; it won't allow all characters as utfmb4 does.  though it will work for `ž` or `ć`.  don't know what "didn't work for the init script" means

Comment: @ysth the init script is a feature of the official docker container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the initialisation script is not being properly run because you have an existing volume. MySQL checks if `/var/lib/mysql` already exists and will only run those scripts if it doesn't.

So first do

```
docker-compose down -v
```

Then use `docker volume ls` to check that the associated volume is gone. Now do `docker-compose up`.

```
├── docker-compose.yml
├── mysql-init
│   └── create-table.sql
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql-init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
    command: --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

volumes:
  mysql_data:
```

`mysql-init/create-table.sql` An initialisation script that creates table using the code provided and then inserts a record with non-ASCII characters.

```
CREATE TABLE `vodovod_ulice` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `naziv` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `naziv` (`naziv`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

insert into vodovod_ulice (naziv) values ('Ulica Vuka Karadžića');
```

Check the content of the table to confirm that the characters are represented correctly.

[image]

Comment: thanks it does work, but for some reason in datagrip for example it's not able to show those characters.

Comment: I suspect that's a Datagrip issue not a Docker one!

Comment: avoid utfmb3; it won't allow all characters as utfmb4 does

Comment: Thank you! I have updated my answer accordingly.